# Ruby - How to create a program that will create a .doc file and display user input?

Tags: ruby, user-input

In Ruby I want to create a program that will accept user input, and display a message in a .doc file that the program creates. I am completely new to ruby, and if I am totally off the mark feel-free to suggest a site that I can look how to do this up on. My code is returning "3:in ' undefined method 'doc' for 0: Fixnum ". The program, as is, will execute the first line of code and display "Hello Friend. What is your name?" before showing error.

```
puts "Hello Friend. What is your name?"
testingruby = 0
File.open(testingruby.doc, 'w') {|f| f.write(doc) }
  STDOUT.flush
  name = gets.chomp
    if name != "David"
      f.puts "That's incorrect." + " " + name
    else
      f.puts "Hello " + name + "!" + " I hope you are well. Welcome to Ruby."
    end
puts "Program will end in 5 seconds."
sleep 5 # seconds
$end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping `testingruby.doc` in a string: `"testingruby.doc"`.

You've defined a Fixnum `testingruby`, and the program thinks you're trying to access the `doc` property of `testingruby`, when you're just trying to define a filename.

Comment: Awesome. I encourage you to hit the little checkbox underneath the vote counter to "accept" this answer and benefit people who see this later.